# How to fix a visible position's jump of a stage in JavaFX when it starts?

Tags: java, javafx, window

I run a JavaFX program in IDEA on Ubuntu. The window, first, locates on the left-top of the screen, and then I see a jump of the window to a center. How can I handle this?

I've tried different methods of Stage, but it didn't help.

start method

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View/MainMenuView.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Flash Cards");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

MainMenuView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controllers.MainMenuController">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="mainMenu" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0">
         <children>
            <Text layoutX="233.0" layoutY="116.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Flash Cards v1" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="333.419921875">
               <font>
                  <Font size="37.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Button fx:id="trainingButton" layoutX="314.0" layoutY="225.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="172.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #000; -fx-border-width: 2;" text="Training">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="OPEN_HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="addNewWordButton" layoutX="314.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="172.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-color: #000; -fx-border-width: 2;" text="Add a new word">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="OPEN_HAND" />
               </cursor>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I just want the window be in a center immediately when my program starts.

Comment: I faced with this problem too. JavaFX 12.0.2, Ubuntu. Solution from answer doesn't work. But in my case, not primary stage wont apear in right position. After loading primary stage, then showing other stage, and then showing alert (or any other stage) from controller action handler latter doesn't appear in right location. It appears in top-left corner and then jumps to center. UPD: but not always. Sometimes and first stage doesnt appear right

Comment: This seems to be fixed in JavaFX 14 - I'm not seeing this issue after updating from 11.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in JavaFX itself. A workaround for until it is fixed is to do this:

```
primaryStage.show();
primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
```

You need to call `centerOnScreen()` immediately after `show()` to prevent it from showing up in the corner.